# How to show specific properties in the settings

Tags: android, android-layout

In my Android application I have a setting layout with four properties.
You can call the settings from the `MainActivity` and from the `NoticeActivity`. To do this I have overwritten this method:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
 }
```

To show the settings i have these two classes:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
            .commit();
   }
}

public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       // preference_general -> layout with 4 properties
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_general);
   }
}
```

What I want to do is: if the settings are called from the `MainActivity`, I want to show all four properties, but if called from the `NoticeActivity` I want to show just the first three.

How can I do this without creating a second layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by just defining some constant in your intent in both activity.For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Activity","first_activity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Remember, name "Activity" should be same in both activities.
And use checking for calling specific settings in setting activity. For example:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Intent i = getIntent();
   String checkingValue = i.getStringExtra("Activity");

   if(checkingValue != null){   //Or something else
       //setting layout with four properties
   }else{
      //setting layout with three properties
   }
}
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: I hab this idea too. But then I have two layouts which are almost the same. And if i want to make changes at the Settings, I have to change two layouts. I think at some time i will have problems due to that.

Comment: Try hiding some buttons, according to your need. Make the layout with 4 buttons and for showing 3 buttons, hide the 4th button.It should help

Answer (score 0):

I got this working for me. Don't know if it is well programmed.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String activity = getIntent().getStringExtra("Activity"); // Before starting Intent, put class name as Extra

    if (activity != null && activity.equals("Main")) { 
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment_Main())
                .commit();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment_Notice())
                .commit();
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

public static class SettingsFragment_Main extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_general);
    }
}

public static class SettingsFragment_Notice extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // first set layout, otherwise the preference will be null
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_general);

        // Disable the Preference
        Preference preference = findPreference(Constants.FOLDER_DEST_SETTING_KEY);
        preference.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
}
```